# Wordpress custom post type - list only UPCOMING events - not ALL events

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a custom post type for events, with a field to display the event_date.
At the moment, my code pulls in EVERY event. 
I need to to only pull in events that have NOT passed.

Any advice on how I can only select posts that occur in the future?
That is, show only UPCOMING EVENTS.

My code so far (ignore the google maps part)...

```
<?php
$mapposts = new WP_Query( array( 
'post_status' => 'publish', 
'post_type' => 'tour-date',
'posts_per_page'  => -1
) );
?>

<div class="acf-map">
<?php while ( $mapposts->have_posts() ) : $mapposts->the_post(); ?>
<?php
$location = get_field('event_map');
$gtemp = explode (',',  implode($location));
$coord = explode (',', implode($gtemp));
?>

<div class="marker" data-lat="<?php echo $location[lat]; ?>" data-lng="<?php echo $location[lng]; ?>">

<h1><?php if(get_field('event_date'))
{
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', get_field('event_date'));
echo $date->format('M j');
}                        
?></h1>
<h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>  
</div>

<?php endwhile; ?>

</div><!-- .acf-map -->


  <?php
    $args=array(        
    'post_type' => 'tour-date',        
    'orderby'=> 'event_date',        
    'order' => 'ASC'        
    );        
    $my_query = null;        
    $my_query = new WP_Query($args);        
    if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {        
    echo '';        
    $i = 0;        
    while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();        
    if($i % 3 == 0) { ?> 
  <?php
    }        
    ?>
  <div class="box-shadow">
    <ul class="event">
      <li class="date">
        <?php if(get_field('event_date'))
          {              
          $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', get_field('event_date'));              
          echo $date->format('M j');              
          }              
          ?>
      </li>
      <li class="location"><?php the_field('event_city'); ?></li>
      <li class="venue"><?php the_field('event_venue'); ?></li>
      <li class="country"><?php the_field('event_country'); ?></li>
      <li class="details"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">+ Info</a></li>
      <li class="purchase"><a href="<?php the_field('event_tickets'); ?>" class="purchase" target="_blank">Tickets</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- /box-shadow -->
  <?php    
    if($i % 3 == 0) { ?> 
  <?php
    }        
    $i++;        
    endwhile;        
    }        
    wp_reset_query();        
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some playing I came up with this solution that works...

```
$event1 = current_time('Ymd');
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'tour-date',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
        'key' => 'event_date',
        'compare' => '>=',
        'value' => $event1,
        )
        ),
    'meta_key' => 'event_date',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'ASC',
);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how it should be

```
<?php
$events = get_posts(array(
                'post_type'     => 'tour-date',
                'posts_per_page'=> -1,
                'meta_key'      => 'event_date',
                'orderby'       => 'meta_value',
                'order'         => 'ASC'
            ));

foreach($events as $event){

    $event_date = get_post_custom_values('event_date',$event->ID);
    $event_date = $event_date[0];
    list($y,$m,$d) = explode('-',$event_date);
    $ym = $y.'-'.$m;


    if($event_date<date('Y-m-d')) continue;
?>
```

Comment: unfortunately that breaks the site.
My code works fine, i just need it to stop showing dates that have already expired.

Comment: u need to close the <?php tag.. after the html code is put make sure u add <?php } ?> and that will fix it

Comment: put u r whole code for this section. i'll edit it and repost the answer. nor just the argument if u cant figure it out

Comment: This method is not efficient as you're still requesting all the posts from the database. If the user has thousands of old events this query could timeout.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your storing the date as a timestamp you can add a `meta_compare` parameter to your query...

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'tour-date',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_key' => 'event_date',
    'meta_value' => current_time( 'timestamp' ),
    'meta_compare' => '>=',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);
```

Give that a go

Dan

Comment: Thanks dan, I have posted full query above now in case that helps work out why i can't get it.

Comment: @lowercase Have you tried my answer? just replace your $args array with mine and it should work. Although I don't understand why you have 2 instances of wp_query in your code.

Comment: do you think i can combine the two instances?
One controls the google map markers for events and the other controls the listing of events.

Comment: Hi Dan,  I added that new query but ALL events are still listing unfortunately. Any other ideas that may help? Much appreciated.

Comment: @lowercase The query I wrote in my answer is 100% correct. If it's still not working for you my guess would be that having 2 instances of wp_query on your page is messing it up but it's hard for me to say. The other option is that you aren't storing your post meta correctly. Try using my query on a completely separate page on it's own and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

this is how the code shoud be written according to my above method. but i agree with dabbharami the issue  with calling all posts. u r method looks good so i think u will no longer need this

```
  <?php
  $events = get_posts(array(
          'post_type'   => 'tour-date',
          'posts_per_page'=> -1,
          'meta_key'    => 'event_date',
          'orderby'     => 'meta_value',
          'order'     => 'ASC'
        ));

  $i=0;
  foreach($events as $event){

    $event_date = get_post_custom_values('event_date',$event->ID);
    $event_date = $event_date[0];
    list($y,$m,$d) = explode('-',$event_date);
    $ym = $y.'-'.$m;


    if($event_date<date('Y-m-d')) continue;
  ?>
  <div class="box-shadow">
    <ul class="event">
      <li class="date">
        <?php if(get_field('event_date'))
          {              
          $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', get_field('event_date'));              
          echo $date->format('M j');              
          }              
          ?>
      </li>
      <li class="location"><?php the_field('event_city'); ?></li>
      <li class="venue"><?php the_field('event_venue'); ?></li>
      <li class="country"><?php the_field('event_country'); ?></li>
      <li class="details"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">+ Info</a></li>
      <li class="purchase"><a href="<?php the_field('event_tickets'); ?>" class="purchase" target="_blank">Tickets</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- /box-shadow -->
  <?php
    $i++;
    if($i==3) break;
  }
  ?>
```